# Pass parameter to remote SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, grep, remote-access

I have a function:

```
function obtener_resumen(){
 ssh  root@${1} '
   echo "grep -iE ${2} ${3}";
   ifconfig;
 ' > "${4}"
}
```

I call it:

```
obtener_resumen "MY_IP" "PATRON" "/MY_FILE.txt" "/demo.log"
```

When I open demo.log only I see:

```
grep -iE
```

When I need `grep -iE PATRON /MY_FILE.txt`

It's possible this?. I appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the expansion to happen on the client side, so you can use double quotes to expand the value before it's passed to `ssh`:

```
# Unsafe version
function obtener_resumen(){
 ssh  root@${1} "
   echo \"grep -iE ${2} ${3}\";
   ifconfig;
  " > "${4}"
}
```

But to prevent command injection, use `printf %q`:

```
#Safe version
function obtener_resumen(){
 ssh  root@${1} "$(printf "%q " echo grep -iE "$2" "$3"); ifconfig" > "$4"
}
```